# Server error viewing revision history or timeline of a specific post

Tags: bug, status-completed, revision-history, timeline

Looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68961185/revisions) or [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68961185/timeline) of: [Tally counter returns blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961185/tally-counter-returns-blank-page) results in the generic server error message:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> ...

This post was also pushed into the reopen review queue by an edit as shown in the close banner, however the review isn't reviewable. Filtering for Duplicates tagged [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) gives the error:

> An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.

Comment: You also can't view a specific revision of the post. Even trying to see a revision that wouldn't exist (#100: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68961185/100) gives an error (should be a 404).

Comment: @Laurel Right, but you can view specific revisions using the Rev dropdown in the edit page: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68961185/edit/c7b329b3-f356-4eea-b0bd-a4552b142316

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed now.

> Specific edge case
> when significant edit
> messed up timeline load